# Files getting custom Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, modern-experience

I’m using the modern library but once I’m uploading  a new file it already getting Metadata.
When I upload a new file, I want it to be shown that his fire requires attention, so that the user goes and fills the attributes

Answer (score 0):

In the modern lists this is not an option however the list item will be shown in the Attention list view and the mandatory fields will be marked in the details view for that item.
The only way to promt the user to provide a value for the mandatory fields is to revert to the classic list mode

Answer (score 0):

It is by designer that it doesn't prompting for Metadata in the New Document Library Experience when you upload a document.

You can add the Metadata by using "Quick Edit" or choose a document and choose "open the details panel".

For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

http://www.sharepointfocus.com/sharepoint/prompting-meta-data-new-document-library-experience/